# spyder python3.9 tensorflow 2.6(support gpu) from tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental import dtensor as dtensor_api error

Tags: python, tensorflow

*why do I have error?*

Error message :

```
File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\.spyder-py3\GPU\UsingTensorflowBasic.py", line 18, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\api\_v2\keras\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from keras import __version__

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from keras import models

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras.engine.functional import Functional

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras import backend

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 34, in <module>
    from keras.engine import keras_tensor

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\keras_tensor.py", line 19, in <module>
    from keras.utils import object_identity

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from keras.utils.layer_utils import get_source_inputs

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\layer_utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from keras import initializers

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from keras.initializers import initializers_v2

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers\initializers_v2.py", line 23, in <module>
    from keras.dtensor import utils

  File "C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\dtensor\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental import dtensor as dtensor_api

ImportError: cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental' (C:\Users\Tibame_EX14\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v2\experimental\__init__.py)

import datetime

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import LearningRateScheduler

model.evaluate(test_dataset)

model.save('model.h5')
```

I want to use gpu(GEforce MX550) to spyder(anaconda3)

so I reinstalled an3 and installed tensorflow_gpu-2.6.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl

I also installed cuda 11.2 and cuDNN 8

but I have error with using tensorflow

`tensorflow.test.is_gpu_available()` responses True.

please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem
open anaconda powershell prompt use this

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.9
```

and then spyder not happen error
I check my pip list find 2 tensorflow
tensorflow-gpu                2.6.0
tensorflow                    2.9.0
luckiy gpu also can run :)
but you have to download zlibwapi.dll put in your project
if can't slove try to use
conda anaconda powershell prompt use
install -c anaconda cudnn

Comment: if still erroe  try add path in spyder following ->tool -> pythonpath manager  -> project path